# Not able to use the passed $_GET variable for button click

Tags: php, html

I am trying to create a news website. By clicking on a news category in navigation bar (which is a link to another page, lets say `newsPolitics.php`), users can see the preview of all news from that category. Each of these news is a link to the full article.

I have a small PHP script inside HTML tags to fetch news from a database and display them:

```
<?php
  require_once("../Controller/newsBL.php");
  $newsBL = new NewsBL();
  $politicsNews = $newsBL -> FetchNewsInPolitics();

  $numberOfNews = count($politicsNews);

  foreach($politicsNews as $row) 
  {
    $newsTitle = $row['newsTitle'];
    $newsText = $row['newsText'];
    $shortNewsText = substr($newsText,0,100)."... Read more.";

    $news = $newsBL -> FetchNewsId($newsTitle, $newsText);

    $newsId = $news["@aId"];
                        
    echo 
    '<div id="news" class="news">
      <a href="news.php?id='.$newsId.'">
        <h2 id="politicsNewsTitle">
          '.$newsTitle.'
        </h2>
        <p id="politicsNewsText" class="newsText">
          '.$shortNewsText.'
        </p>s
      </a>
    </div>';
 ?>
```

On the `news.php` page I have this variable:

```
$newsId = $_GET['id'];
```

I use `$newsId` to dynamically populate the `news.php` page based on the link a user came from and all of this works fine.

Here is my problem: on the same `news.php` page I have a form with submit button (for users to add comments to that specific news). When I try to pass `$newsId` to the function to be executed on the button click, I get this:

```
"Notice: Undefined index: id".
```

UPDATE:

Here is the method from Data Access Class:

```
public function CreateComment($commentText, $newsId, $userId)
    {
        $conn = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "root", "news");

        if($conn -> connect_error)
        {
            die("There was an connection error. Please try again.");
        }
        else 
        {
            $insertString = "CALL sp_CreateComment('".$commentText."', ".$newsId.", ".$userId.");";
            
            $insert = $conn -> real_query($insertString);

            if ($insert == true) 
                {
                    return true;
                }
            else 
                {
                    return false;
                }
        }
        $conn -> close();            
    }
```

Here is the Business Logic class:

```
public function CreateComment($newsId)
    {
        $commentText = trim($_GET['commentText']);
        $userId = $_SESSION['userid'];

        if (ISSET($_GET['commentText'], $_SESSION['userid']) && $commentText != "") 
        {
            $commentDAL = new commentDAL();
            $checkCreated = $commentDAL -> CreateComment($commentText, $newsId, $userId);

            if ($checkCreated == true) 
            {
                header("Refresh:0");
            }
            else 
            {
                echo "<script>alert('Comment could not be created. Please try again with different text.')</script>";
            }   
        }
        else 
        {
            echo "<script>alert('Please enter the comment first.')</script>";
        }
    }
```

And here is the method call from the news.php:
(Please don't judge the lack of JS. This is a PHP excercise :)):

```
<?php
    require_once("../Controller/commentBL.php");

    $newsId = $_GET['id'];

    if (array_key_exists('addComment',$_GET)) 
    {
        $commentBL = new CommentBL();
        $commentBL -> CreateComment($newsId);
    }
?>
```

This last call produces the error I mentioned in the beginning ("Notice: Undefined index: id".).

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: So the posted code works and you have some other code (the form) where it doesn't?

Comment: You are right. I will delete my previous comment, not to confuse.

Comment: If you have some specific issues with your code, you need to show us the code that _doesn't_ work. Please read [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and [How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and edit your question accordingly.

Comment: Is the form method == GET?

Comment: @MGE, I assume it is GET. I tried to be consistent. I update the entire code, so please take a look again.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson I updated the rest of the code. Thanks for pointing out the need to add it.